# How to delete a row in dojo EnhancedGrid using row index not by using selection

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

Trying to find an answer to remove a row for dojo EnhancedGrid based on the row index.

Please find the EnhancedGrid.

```
    var dataStore = new ObjectStore({objectStore: objectStoreMemory});
    // grid
    grid = new EnhancedGrid({
    selectable: true,
    store: dataStore,
    structure : [ {
        name : "Country",
        field : "Country",
        width : "150px",
        reorderable: false,
        editable : true
    }, {
        name : "Abbreviation",
        field : "Abbreviation",
        width : "120px",
        reorderable: false,
        editable : true
    }, {
        name : "Capital",
        field : "Capital",
        width : "100%",
        reorderable: false,
        editable : true
    }, {
        label: "", 
        field: "Delete",
        formatter: deleteButton
    }],
    rowSelector: '20px',
    plugins: {
        pagination: {
            pageSizes: ["10", "25", "50", "100"],
            description: true,
            sizeSwitch: true,
            pageStepper: true,
            gotoButton: true,
            maxPageStep: 5,
            position: "bottom"
        }
    }
    }, "grid");
    grid.startup();
```

And the Delete Button Script is here:

```
function deleteButton(id) {
    var dBtn1 = "<div data-dojo-type='dijit/form/Button'>";
    var dBtn2 = "<img src='delete.png' onclick='javascript:removeItem()' alt='" + id + "'";
    dBtn = dBtn1 + dBtn2 + " width='18' height='18'></div>";
    return dBtn;
}
```

Here is my Question: Each row will have a delete button at the end, On click of this button the same row should be deleted.

Can anybody tell me how to delete a row based on row index?

Comment: @Manjunatha Muniyappa Do you have any solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution. The sequence of methods that will run onClick of a button are removeItem() and onRowClick event

1> Set the "deleteButtonFlag" on click of a button.

```
function removeItem() {
        deleteButtonGFlag = true;
}
```

2> Remove item

```
dojo.connect(grid, "onRowClick", function(e) {
    if (deleteButtonGFlag) {
        dataStore.fetch({
            query: {},
            onComplete: function(items) {
                var item = items[e.rowIndex];
                dataStore.deleteItem(item);
                dataStore.save();
                deleteButtonGFlag = false;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> If you want to add (remove) data programmatically, you just have to
>   add (remove) it from the underlying data store. Since DataGrid is
>   “DataStoreAware”, changes made to the store will be reflected
>   automatically in the DataGrid.

https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/grid/example_Adding_and_deleting_data.html

dojox/grid has a property `selection` and method `getSelected()` to get selected items. In example from documentation it's implemented in following way:

```
        var items = grid5.selection.getSelected();
        if(items.length){
            // Iterate through the list of selected items.
            // The current item is available in the variable
            // "selectedItem" within the following function:
            dojo.forEach(items, function(selectedItem){
                if(selectedItem !== null){
                    // Delete the item from the data store:
                    store3.deleteItem(selectedItem);
                } // end if
            }); // end forEach
        } // end if
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: Actually this solution works very well for ItemFileWriteStore but it is not working for ObjectStore.  Do you know how to get the row index on button click.